# how can i store/retrieve files in owncloud from a webapp written in opal/ruby?

Tags: ruby, webdav, owncloud, opalrb

I have a webapp written mostly in ruby compiled with opal. I now would like to store/retrieve file in my owncloud, maybe using WebDAV. I am looking for an example how to do this using HTTP module.

I tried

```
HTTP.get("https://owncloud/foo.abc") do |req|
   req.username= "user"
   ...
end.then do |response|
   puts response
end
```

But that does not work. no method then for module HTTP.

So it seem that if I pass a block to HTTP.get it no longer returns a promise.

When I do not pass a block I don' know 
how to configure the request.

Best if I could find an full example how to use HTTP from opal.
The small example in opal blog die not hell out.

Answer (score 0):

I think username/password should be passed in the options hash ([see the opal-jquery README](https://github.com/opal/opal-jquery#httpajax-requests)).

```
HTTP.get("https://owncloud/foo.abc", username: 'user').then do |response|
   puts response
end
```

#### A note about the Promise-style:

The block is used as the default form of callback. To switch to promise-style you should not pass any block, instead try assigning the result of `HTTP.get` to a variable to modify the request options:

```
req = HTTP.get("https://owncloud/foo.abc")

puts req.inspect # <= do something with the request

req.then do |response|
   puts response
end
```

Comment: I am a bit confused where to find information about HTTP: There is something in opal-browser, somehtin in opal-jquery

Comment: In particular I never know when HTTP.get retuns a Promise and when a HTTP. Does it also depend on the Opal version? Im a playing around in http://opalrb.org/try/# resp. in http://fkchang.github.io/opal-irb/index-jq.html

Comment: @fkchang's irb report opal 0.6.0 and it doesn't have support for Promise

Comment: `HTTP` is part of `opal-jquery` and it's a wrapper for `$.ajax` and [looking at the changelog](https://github.com/opal/opal-jquery/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#edge) you can see promises support has not yet been released